# Specify application server to run rufus-scheduler with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I have some configuration code inside of a configure do block in config.ru which reads the following:

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
scheduler.every '1h' do
  # Run a cleanup job which should take place every hour
  ...
end
```

When we deploy our sinatra application on engineyard, by default the rufus-scheduler threads are spawned on the app master, although we would like for them to be spawned on one of the other application servers inside of engineyard. Is there a good way to accomplish this without having a conditional block inside of before_restart.rb? The documentation doesn't seem to go into this.

deploy/before_restart.rb:

```
if node[:name] == "app_instance_1" 
  scheduler.every '1h' do
    # Run cleanup job
  end
```

end

The scheduler.every block might have to be encapsulated inside of a rake task. 
Any input is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate mini application that does the scheduling, remove the scheduling from your main application.

OR

Check the hostname in your config.ru:

```
Kernel.load('deploy/scheduling.rb') if node[:name] == "app_instance_1"
```

and remove the conditional from deploy/before_restart.rb

OR

so many ways to skin a cat...

**Note**:

> The documentation doesn't seem to go into this.

It's because it's so context-dependent.

Comment: Unfortunately `node` variable is out of scope in config.ru. And trying to identify the hostname doesn't work either because the internal DNS hostname could change. The mini application might work, could add it to monit and have it provisioned to run on the app instance. it just seems like overkill. I'll try going the mini app route and upvote if it works, thanks for your time :)

Comment: OK, you didn't mention that in your question. You really have no way to tell a specific deploy to run or not to run the scheduler? There could be some empty file whose mere presence indicates that the scheduler should be initialized and "populated", or the inverse, a file that tells the app not to initialize / run the scheduler... With a bit of imagination and two steps back to get a wider picture, it shouldn't be too hard.